# Escaping string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, query-string

I have a problem on my application. When I need to enter name (unlimited num of rows), I need to make a query string of this. If I enter character "&" in field, then querystring for two first_name instances will be `[['first_name=&&'], ['first_name=&&&&']]` So that makes a problem for me. How to escape those characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to create your quote string, using name and value pairs:

```
from urllib import urlencode

items = [('first_name', '&&'), ('first_name', '&&&&')]
query_string = urlencode(items)
```

This encodes your ampersands correctly:

```
>>> urlencode(items)
'first_name=%26%26&first_name=%26%26%26%26'
```